# how to get average time 'xx:xx:xx' on mysql?

Tags: mysql

please see the the test data bellow. I want to get the avgtime (=timeonsite/visits) and display as "xx:xx:xx" result in mysql. how can I get it?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `t`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `timeOnsite` time default NULL,
  `visits` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('1', '04:05:30', '20');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('2', '03:00:00', '10');
INSERT INTO `t` VALUES ('3', '00:01:30', '17');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure that you calculate avgtime in such way?
If yes, mysql select below:

```
select id, timeOnsite,visits, SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(timeOnsite)/visits) as avgtime
from t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TIME_TO_SEC` function to change `xx:xx:xx` format to seconds.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:01:30') / 17;  # return 5.2941
```

And then through `SEC_TO_TIME` you can convert seconds to time back as below :

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('00:01:30') / 17);  # return 00:00:05
```